# Insert an image into pdf (Adobe Acrobat Pro) using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, acrobat

This is what I want to do:

```
.this.getField('imageField').importImage('path_to_img');
```

I know this code is not correct, but is there a way to do this? I couldn't find the solution in Acrobat's documentation.

I need to do it using javascript because `path_to_image` is a variable I'm pulling from a database...

Comment: You may want to look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25323427/924) about inserting images into a PDF using JavaScript. It appears you can, there are just some interesting things to work around in Acrobat depending on the version (like importing the image as an icon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an anwser on Adobe forums. Here is the full discussion:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/8694023#8694023

```
var f = this.getField("btnImage");
f.buttonSetCaption("Title");
  if (f.buttonImportIcon("/C/image.pdf") == 0){  // if 0 == no error
      f.buttonImportIcon("/C/image.pdf");
  }
```

Also when you are setting a button you have to select an option "Icon only" for this to work.